# Does rm -rf /mnt/ delete files in subfolders if you do not have write access to /mnt/?

Tags: root, rm, delete, write

I accidentally ended up with `rm -rf some-text-folder-I-had-already-deleted-previously.txt /mnt/` because of arrow up into bash history.

My screen flashed with lots of subfolders that I actually do have write permissions for (I don't have write permission for /mnt/, so even the mount folders inside /mnt/ have been created with sudo mkdir) but all of the lines ended with Operation not permitted (and I stopped the command before it could finish).

I am worried that files inside those folders might have been deleted because a `df -h` the previous day showed one file server volume **85%** and 24 hours later it's **83%**. But I do have some scripts cleaning up old files on that file server volume, so that could be the reason.

Since the stuff up, I haven't been able to find any missing files (I even have two tree -ahfq daily outputs files that I have diff'ed, but the ones missing from file2 are not actually deleted as far as I can see).

Can a simple `rm -rf /mnt/` actually do harm to subfolders and files if I don't actually own or have write permissions to `/mnt/` (owned by root etc as default on Ubuntu)?

Comment: @rohit, they probably didn't end up with a command with quotes around the whole command line, as that would likely only give an error

Comment: They had it there, I guess for emphasis.  So, you are right, I should have removed them.

Answer (score 1):

> Does rm -rf /mnt/ delete files in subfolders if you do not have write access to /mnt/?

Yes, it does.

It runs recursively so it will delete everything it can and show an error for files/directories it doesn't have access to.

The coreutils version has a nice flag `-I`: *prompt once before removing more than three files, or when removing recursively; less intrusive than -i, while still giving protection against most mistakes* though I'm not sure how it works with `-f`: *ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt*.

Comment: I think the last one of `-f`/`-i`/`-I` applies.